# xlsxwriter: conditional formatting - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_get_dxf_index'

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a column using `xlsxwriter`.

I keep getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_get_dxf_index'` using the following code:

```
import xlsxwriter

xlsx_file = REPORTS + "\\" + project + report_date + '_inventory_init.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
wb = writer.book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Not Supported', startrow = 1, header=False, index=False)
ws = writer.sheets['Not Supported']
ws.conditional_format('G1:G1048576', {'type': 'cell',
                                       'criteria': '==',
                                       'value': 'FALSE',
                                       'format': 'Bad'})

(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in df.columns]
ws.add_table(0,0,max_row,max_col-1,{'columns': column_settings,
                                     'style': 'Table Style Medium 8'})
ws.set_column(0, max_col-1,15)
```

Full error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-b1f6e2d0bdf4> in <module>
     47 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Not Supported', startrow = 1, header=False, index=False)
     48 ws = writer.sheets['Not Supported']
---> 49 ws.conditional_format('G1:G1048576', {'type': 'cell',
     50                                        'criteria': '==',
     51                                        'value': 'FALSE',

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py in cell_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     98             args = new_args
     99 
--> 100         return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    101 
    102     return cell_wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py in conditional_format(self, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col, options)
   2280         # Get the dxf format index.
   2281         if 'format' in options and options['format']:
-> 2282             options['format'] = options['format']._get_dxf_index()
   2283 
   2284         # Set the priority based on the order of adding.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_get_dxf_index'
```

Comment: The error is arising because the `str` `'Bad'` doesn't have an attribute or method `__get_dxf_index()` -- is `'Bad'` a valid `'format'` option?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I think that is a likely problem. I will try and find a list of format names in excel. I thought that one was listed.

Comment: May be worth reading [The Format Class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format) docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading [the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html), you need to pass `format=[format object]` instead of `format=[str]` as an option to `ws.conditional_format`.

For more info about how to create a `format` object, see [the `format` docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format).

*For what it's worth:* In a brief search, I wasn't able to find anything about using already-existing-in-Excel-template formatting; it looks like you'll need to create/define your own formatting.